# Working in Germany as a non EU

Tags: visa, germany, non-citizens

My fiancé wants to work in Germany and he is a Lebanese passport holding citizen. He has an Electrical Engineering degree from the American University of Beirut and has been working for the past 4 years at a very reputable company here in Beirut (Dar Al Handasah). He is currently learning German.
My question is, how easy/ difficult is it for him to get a job and a work visa in Germany?
Appreciate your replies..